# how to get fastboot state in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bootloader, fastboot

I want the fastboot status on vb.net

I use this command to check the status of the device's adb

```
        Dim devicestate, fastbootdetect As String
    android.UpdateDeviceList()
    If (android.HasConnectedDevices) Then
        devicestate = Adb.ExecuteAdbCommand(Adb.FormAdbCommand("get-state"))

            If devicestate = "device" Then
            PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Lime
```

But have a problem checking fastboot status
I use this command

```
fastbootdetect = Fastboot.ExecuteFastbootCommand(Fastboot.FormFastbootCommand("devices"))

If fastbootdetect = "fastboot" Then
            PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue
            lblAutoConnect.Text = "Device found in fastboot ! "
            lblModelNumber.Text = "--"
            lblVersion.Text = "--"
            lblBrandName.Text = "--"
```

In the fastboot command, press the  command The output is as follows

> 5a52461 fastboot

5a52461 is different in every model

The command I run above just checks for "fastboot"

But the output is "5a52461 fatboot"

What is the command to check Existence the "fastboot" on the output?

Comment: `If fastbootdetect.Contains("fastboot") Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
If fastbootdetect.Contains("fastboot") Then
    '...run your code here
End If
```

You can also use `Like`:

```
If fastbootdetect Like "*fastboot*" Then
    '...run your code here
End If
```

---

Please note: both functions are case sensitive.

If you want to ignore the case:

```
If fastbootdetect.ToLower.Contains("fastboot") Then
    '...run your code here
End If
```

You can also use `Like`:

```
If fastbootdetect.ToLower Like "*fastboot*" Then
    '...run your code here
End If
```